# Depurar PHP con xDebug en VS Code. Xampp instalado en otra computadora de la red local

Tags: php, vscode, xampp, xdebug

En mi computadora tengo instalado VS Code con la extensión PHP Debug que incluye xDebug 3.2.2. En otra computadora de la red local está instalado y configurado xampp.

En el archivo hosts de mi computadora está mapeada la ip del ordenador donde está instalado xampp con el nombre **websrv.local**.

En mi computadora he mapeado una unidad de red (w) que apunta a la carpeta xampp:
w = \websrv.local\d$\xampp.

En la configuración de xDebug tengo los siguientes valores:

```
"php.debug.executablePath": "w:\\php\\ext\\php_xdebug.dll",
"php.validate.executablePath": "w:\\php\\php.exe",
```

En la computadora de xampp he copiado el archivo php_xdebug.dll en D:\xampp\php\ext y he añadido las siguientes entradas en el archivo php.ini (tal y como lo indica el asistente de instalación):

```
zend_extension = xdebug
[xDebug]
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
```

Cuando intento depurar un programa simple xdebug intenta hacerlo pero sale el mensaje **spawn UNKNOWN**. He leído que este error puede refiere a que no encuentra la dll en la ruta especificada **w:\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el contenido del archivo launch.json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
    
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 0,
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes"
            ],
            "env": {
                "XDEBUG_MODE": "debug,develop",
                "XDEBUG_CONFIG": "client_port=${port}"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch Built-in web server",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.mode=debug",
                "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes",
                "-S",
                "localhost:0"
            ],
            "program": "",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "port": 9003,
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "pattern": "Development Server \\(http://localhost:([0-9]+)\\) started",
                "uriFormat": "http://localhost:%s",
                "action": "openExternally"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Gracias.

Comment: estas seguro que esos son los path y estan correctos?

Comment: Los paths están de acuerdo a la unidad de red. En la computadora que hace de servidor web (websrv.local) XAMPP está instalado en el directorio raíz de la unidad D y la ruta mapeada en la unidad de red de mi computadora es W que apunta  a \\websrv.local\d$\xampp por tanto las rutas de acceso a php.exe y la php.xdebug.dll son w:\php\php.exe y w:\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll. Creo que el problema es que PHP está instalado en la computadora que hace de servidor y no en la que desarrollo.